# How to write UnitTest for a websocket notification class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure how i can mock the websocket.serve method and other methods of websocket module,
Need help in creating a unittest for this class.
if anyone help in creating unittest for these methods?

I want to wroite unit test for this python file, I am not sure how to mock a websocket and how to write a unit test for this particular python file, can anyone please help with some test cases .

```
import websockets
class WebSocketNotif(NotifBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.log = Logger(module = "modulename").create()
        self.__config = CommonConfig("config.json")
        self.websocket_host = "localhost"
        self.websocket_port = self.__config["websocket_port"] if "websocket_port" in self.__config 
        else 8081
        self.push_frequency_seconds = int(self.__config["notification_frequency"])*60\
            if "notification_frequency" in self.__config else 600
        self.serve_forever = True
    
    def start_server(self):
        start_server = websockets.serve(self.notify,self.websocket_host, self.websocket_post)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_untill_complete(start_server)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    
    def stop_server(self):
        self.serve_forever = False

    async def __serve_connection_status(self, websocket):
        while self.serve_forever:
            to_send, _ = self.get_connection_status()
            try:
                to_send = json.dumps(to_send)
                await websocket.send(str(to_send))
                await asyncio.sleep(self.push_frequency_seconds)
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                break
    
    async def __serve_install_status(self,websocket):
        while self.serve_forever:
            to_send, _ = self.get_install_status()
            try:
                to_send = json.dumps(to_send)
                await websocket.send(str(to_send))
                await asyncio.sleep(self.push_frequency_seconds)
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                break

    async def __serve_download_status(self, websocket):
        while self.serve_forever:
            to_send, _ = self.get_download_status()
            try:
                await websocket.send(str(to_send))
                await asyncio.sleep(self.push_frequency_seconds)
            except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
                break

    async def notify(self, websocket, path)
        if "notify/download" in path:
            await self.__serve_download_status(websocket)
        elif "notify/install" in path:
            await self.__serve_install_status(websocket)
        elif "notify/connection" in path:
            await self.__serve_connection_status(websocket)
        else:
            await websocket.send('{"status":"Invalid URL"')


if __name__ = "__main__"
    WebSocketNotif().start_server()
```

Comment: Please, next time provide working code. Also include what do you need to test.

Comment: Please help in  writing the unit test for this code.

Comment: @MaxSmirnov here is more detailed one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71629517/i-want-to-write-the-unit-test-for-the-notify-function-but-i-am-getting-error-w
please check if something can help

Comment: provided code isn't complete and don't even work. Because of that I can't figure out which logic needs to be unit-tested. Provided question does not help me to understand anything, it is resolved and haves no any information but mocking error. Please, complete your question with what exactly you want to test.

Comment: @MaxSmirnov i have updated the full code, i just wanted to write a unit test for this python file.
But i dont know how to do it.
can you please see the updated code now and guide me with some example code how i can write unit test for this code , i am using pytest

Comment: `asyncio def`? Have you even tested that code?

Comment: @md2perpe sry thats async only, 
actually i cannot copy and paste here, so i have written the code . please ignore typo mistakes.

Comment: You can test `.notify()` method. For that you should create fake class `FakeWebsocket` with async method `.send(...)`. Then call method `.notify()` with instance of this fake class and path, only thing to left is to assert expected results with actually sent (you should store arguments of `.send()` calls)